# Where are my received voice notes saved?

Tags: file-system, whatsapp-messenger

I checked in the whatsapp media voice notes. But they are not there. Plz help me to find them urgently.

Answer (score 0):

They're in the directory:
*/whatsapp/media/WhatsApp Voice

Comment: What's the "*" supposed to represent? Where does one find this directory?

Comment: it represents the main directory ("/sdcard")